# How close soft keyboard of previous application?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have an application with custom keyboard on first screen.
It works o'key! But in some cases application opens with custom and native keyboards...
for example: i am writing an sms, receive notification from my app and click on it (soft keyboard from sms-app still open).
In this case will open my application with both keyboards...
*take a look on screenshot*
[image]

So any method like next one are not working, cos in my just opened application none view have focus and view = null:

```
View view = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

any ideas how can I close all previously opened keyboards from other apps?

Comment: Please add proper screen shot as it isn't visible in `Question`.

Comment: @jaydroider, so, any ideas?